# Update a field in table when I'm updating a field in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables - `A` and `B`. I have a field in Table `A`, which can be a null or some value; and a field in table B, which can be null or some value. Both are of `nvarchar` type.

Now, I would like to have a sort of event listener that whenever that field in Table `A` changes value, I would like the same value to be appended to the start of Table `B` field.

If I would want to run `UPDATE` statement, I would write:

```
UPDATE B
SET B.myValueFromB = A.myValueFromA + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),B.myValueFromB)
FROM 
A JOIN B on A.Ref_num = B.Task_num  
WHERE A.Ref_Num = --here is the problem
```

I have a form in program that updates the record having specific `A.Ref_num` with values. End result would be whenever I update that record, a mtaching record in Table `B` also gets updated. How can I do something like that?

Comment: Why bother?  Just use a `JOIN` in the queries to get the value that you want.

Comment: I cannot modify the procedure that updates Table `A`. That's why I want to have some sort of event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trigger for this purpose like :

```
  CREATE TRIGGER up_update_your_table
  ON Table_A FOR UPDATE
  AS
  --Your id field to find the corresponding record in the other table (Table B)
  DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(50)
  DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(50)

  SELECT @ID = YourIDFieldInTableA, @Value = YourValueFieldInTableA FROM Inserted 
  --Inserted returns the updated row


  UPDATE Table_B SET YourValueFieldInTableB = @Value WHERE YourIDFieldInTableB = ID
```

Comment: exactly what I needed, didn't know about triggers, thank you.